# How can I get the creation date from a file on plsql

Tags: oracle, file, plsql, timestamp

Can somebody help me to know how can I get the creation date of a file in plsql?

I thought that I can apply the creation date in the name of the file, but the file name cannot be changed, then I need a method that can help me to know when a specific file or a group of file was create.

I've tried to search on internet a similar solution, but I haven't found it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I connect to a UNIX Database, but my PC is Windows 7. I use Toad for Oracle to launch the scripts that connects to the Database.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do what you want from PL/SQL. First, Unix doesn't maintain a creation date on files so you can't get the creation date of a file on a Unix box. Second, even if you were running an OS which *does* maintain file creation date (e.g. Windows or VMS) I don't know of a way to access that from PL/SQL. Third, PL/SQL knows nothing about your client PC - any PL/SQL code you execute runs on the server so you can't access files on your client from PL/SQL.

Comment: If instead I were on the server and I launched the script from there, could there be a way?

Comment: I don't think so. First, Unix doesn't maintain a creation date on files. Second, there's no way that I'm aware of from PL/SQL to get a file's creation date, even if one was available.

Comment: Okey, thanks you anyway.

Comment: @Tomas , How the file used after creation used and need of date ? add create date and then cut the date from name of file is possible

Comment: @kanagaraj , I know, but the name of the file is already defined and i can't change it, thanks anyway.